# How to append memory usage for each step within a shell script in slurm output

Tags: bash, shell, slurm

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G my_code -i my_file_1 -o my_output_file_1
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G my_code -i my_file_2 -o my_output_file_2
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G my_code -i my_file_3 -o my_output_file_3
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G my_code -i my_file_4 -o my_output_file_4
```

I want to know the average memory usage for each step (printed after the real/user/sys time) while the script is running.

I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_1 -o my_output_file_1
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_2 -o my_output_file_2
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_3 -o my_output_file_3
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_4 -o my_output_file_4


sstat -a -j my_job --format=JobName,AveRSS,MaxRSS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#!/bin/bash
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_1 -o my_output_file_1
sstat -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID}.1 --format=JobName,AveRSS,MaxRSS
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_2 -o my_output_file_2
sstat -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID}.2 --format=JobName,AveRSS,MaxRSS
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_3 -o my_output_file_3
sstat -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID}.3 --format=JobName,AveRSS,MaxRSS
time srun -p my_partition -c 1 --mem=4G --job-name"my_job" my_code -i my_file_4 -o my_output_file_4
sstat -j ${SLURM_JOB_ID}.4 --format=JobName,AveRSS,MaxRSS
```